# app engine ndb doesn't invalidate the cache until timeout

Tags: google-app-engine, caching

Is there a way to make the NDB api write to the database without invalidating the cache? This way, people read from the cache untill the timeout has expired, not when some new data has been written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, pass use_memcache=False to the put() operation:

```
  ent.put(use_memcache=False)
```